# Choose all the files of a folder as an input to run a process in the model designer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, iteration

I hope you can help me with this.
I have this in the model designer and I looking for a solution because I need to run this process in many layers (150) and I dont know if is possible to select a folder and all the files as inputs.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute the model as [a batch process](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html).

Press Run model and:
[image]

I select all files with `72` in the name in this folder:
[image]

The tricky part is to name the outputs.
This expression replaces the input path with `C:/TEMP/model_outputs` and use input file name and appends `_output.tif` to the output file name (use forward slashes in path). Replace `@input_raster_layer` to match your input parameter name (yellow input box in first screenshot):

```
 concat(
 replace(
 file_path( @input_raster_layer ),
 file_path( @input_raster_layer ),
 'C:/TEMP/model_outputs'),
  concat('/',
  base_file_name(@input_raster_layer), '_output.tif'))
```

[image]